# Copy files that are created today without FIND command and SFTP to another server

Tags: shell, scripting, ls, cp, sftp

I have a directory with 'n' number of files in it. I am trying to write a shell script which will list only the files created on the particular day the script is running, and will use `sftp` to move the files listed for the day to another server. I don't want to use `find`.

I tried using

```
ls -l  --time-style=+%D | grep $(date +%D) | grep -v '^d'
```

to list the files that are created for today. How do I copy the listed files to another directory, so that I can `sftp` the directory to another server. I tried the below command, but no use

```
ls -l  --time-style=+%D | grep $(date +%D) | grep -v '^d' > /home/oracle/SABARISH/logs/files/
```

And how do I `sftp` using shell script, I have tried `sftp` in command line, but is different when used in script.

Comment: No time to actually figure out the details for you, but you can use `tar --after-date=DATE` to send a tar over stdout.  pipe that through ssh, and untar on the other side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
files=$( ls -l --time-style=+%D | grep $(date +%D) | grep -v '^d' | awk '{print $NF}' ) ; for f in $files ; do cp -rf $f /home/oracle/SABARISH/logs/files/ ; done ; sftp {user}@{host}:{remote_dir} <<< 'put /home/oracle/SABARISH/logs/files/*'
```

or similarly:

```
for f in $(ls -l --time-style=+%D | grep $(date +%D) | grep -v '^d' | awk '{print $NF}') ; cp -rf $f /home/oracle/SABARISH/logs/files/ ; done ; sftp {user}@{host}:{remote_dir} <<< 'put /home/oracle/SABARISH/logs/files/*'
```

Awk is used to extract file names.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$(ls -l test1_*.txt --time-style=+%D | grep ${DATE} | grep -v '^d' | awk '{p rint $NF}' )

if [ -n "${FILES}" ]
then
    for f in ${FILES}
    do
        cp -prf ${f} ${DESTINATION}
    done
    sftp ${USER}@${HOST}:${CD} <<< 'put /home/oracle/SABARISH/logs/sftp/*'
else
    echo "NO FILES TO MOVE"
fi
```

Comment: It is working awesome now. Any idea, how to SFTP that directory to another server in the same script?

Comment: You can add `sftp {user}@{host}:{remote_dir} <<< $'put /home/oracle/SABARISH/logs/files/*` to the end of command. See here for more info on single line sftp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721891/single-line-sftp-from-terminal

Comment: `FILES=$(ls -l test1_*.txt --time-style=+%D | grep ${DATE} | grep -v '^d' | awk '{p rint $NF}' )
if [ -n "${FILES}" ]
then
        for f in ${FILES}
        do
                cp -prf ${f} ${DESTINATION}
        done
        sftp ${USER}@${HOST}:${CD} <<< $'put /home/oracle/SABARISH/logs/sftp/*'
else
        echo "NO FILES TO MOVE"
fi` I have implemented the above code, but after that `<<<` it is showing in red color, is there anyway to fix it. But script is working fine.

Comment: Please use a script when you have many commands to make it easier for yourself and others to read and maintain!

Comment: That was a script block though. I just wanted to learn what `<<<` does!

Comment: @sabarishjackson see section 3.6.7 Here Strings of the bash manual http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use `zsh` shell for this job:

```
cp *(m-1) /home/oracle/SABARISH/logs/files/
```

where `(m-1)` is so called glob qualifier.

In this case we select all (`*`) files modified (`m`) within (`-`) last (`1`) day.